# .htaccess redirect without parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem with `.htaccess` redirect: 
in my site, I already have a file htaccess with this strings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/page/?$ cms.php?lang=$1&livello1=page [L,QSA]
```

and I want to do redirect from "`http://example.com/it/page`" to "`http://newexample.com/negozio/page1`".

My code for redirect is:

```
#REDIRECT
Redirect /it/page http://newexample.com/negozio/page1
```

When I try to do this, the redirect becomes 
http://newexample.com/negozio/page1?lang=it&livello1=page.

How can I delete "`?lang=it&livello1=page`"?

Does "?lang=it&livello1=page" originate from my .htaccess?

Sorry, 
but I found no solutions on google.

Thank's.

Comment: Since you're removing the `it` from the URL it seems to me your CMS is appending it by itself not your `.htaccess` file but the controller of your CMS. It's also possible you may have multiple `.htaccess` that are overwriting each other.

Answer (score 1):

Add a ? at the end of the redirect:

```
#REDIRECT
Redirect /it/page http://newexample.com/negozio/page1?
```

Comment: That works great, but the trailing question mark will also be in the new url - any way to remove that as well?